# Cordova File Plugin - Where are the files saved

Tags: file, cordova, plugins, phonegap

using the Cordova File Plugin where are the files saved?

If you delete the app are the files created with the plugin also deleted?

Are they saved within the App structure?

- res
- www
  | components
  | css
  | lib
  index.html

Answer (score 0):

With Cordova File Plugin you decide where to save files.
You can check out the various options and persistence here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/